# Calculate change from paid amount

Tags: python, python-2.7

Why is this code creating an infinite loop? I would think this should be an appropriate solution for this type of problem. For example, if the price was $5 and you paid $5.47, the program would print:

```
Quarters: 1
Dimes: 2
Nickels: 0
Pennies: 2
```

However, an infinite loop occurs and I'm not sure why. Anyone know the reason?

```
price = round(float(input("Enter the price: ")), 2)
print price
paid = round(float(input("Enter the amount paid: ")), 2)
print paid
change = round(float(paid - price), 2)
print change
quarters = 0
dimes = 0
nickels = 0
pennies = 0
while change > 0.00:
    print change
    if change >= .25:
        change = change - .25
        quarters += 1
        continue
    elif change >= .1:
        change = change - .1
        dimes += 1
        continue
    elif change >= .05:
        change = change - .05
        nickels += 1
    elif change >= .01:
        change = change - .01
        pennies += 1
print "Quarters: " + str(quarters)
print "Dimes: " + str(dimes)
print "Nickels: " + str(nickels)
print "Pennies: " + str(pennies)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `change = paid - price`?

Comment: Note: Python2 is end of life by the end of the year. You may want to learn Python3

Comment: I recommend reading the following article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: Also, just ran the code, and entered 5, then 5.47 and there is no loop.

Comment: No need for all those `continue` statements.

Comment: Your loop is never entered since expression in your while statement is not true, at least for your example -0.47 (change) > 0 is false

Comment: As the previous commented stated you should have "change = paid - price" but in addition your code runs into a common issue subtracting floats where you get more digits than expected. From your example float(5.47) - float(5) = 0.46999999999999975. There are a few libraries that will make working with money a little less problematic.

Comment: Multiply both `price` and `paid` by 100 and then work in cents to avoid floating point representation issues.

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks for the advice! i'm using python 2 for my school course, no other option for me currently. updated the code to represent more what i meant.

Comment: @user1729210 i've just updated the code after realizing i was being stupid, now it should enter the infinite loop.

Comment: @KILLtheWEEZEL would rounding it such as how i have in the new code fix this problem?

Comment: @jarmod would that be a workaround for round() or a better way to do it? just curious, thank you for the helpful response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than dealing with loops, I would suggest just subtracing off the change that you already gathered, prioritizing larger coins.

```
price = float(input("Enter the price: "))
paid = float(input("Enter the amount paid: "))
change = paid - price

if change < 0:
   raise ValueError('Not enough paid')

quarters = change // 0.25
dimes = (change - (0.25 * quarters)) // 0.10
nickels = (change - (0.25 * quarters) - (0.10 * dimes)) // 0.05
pennies = 100 * (change - (0.25 * quarters) - (0.10 * dimes) - (0.05 * nickels))

print("Quarters: {:.0f}".format(quarters))
print("Dimes: {:.0f}".format(dimes))
print("Nickels: {:.0f}".format(nickels))
print("Pennies: {:.0f}".format(pennies))
```

Comment: thanks! works great, just got set on the idea that i would need to do it with loops

Answer (score 0):

There's one minor bug in the code which causes the program to only work correctly if price and amount paid are interchanged (e.g. price = 2, paid = 1). But that is not the issue causing the infinite loop.

Your code creates an infinite loop for e.g. the following arguments:

- price: 5.6
- paid: 5.4

The reason for the infinite loop can be seen from your own print output:

```
0.009999999999999275
0.009999999999999275
0.009999999999999275
0.009999999999999275
0.009999999999999275
0.009999999999999275
0.009999999999999275
...
```

Since `change < 0.01`, no if clause applies and thus the loop is never left.

**How could you solve the problem more robustly?**

Here's a sketch

```
from math import floor
change = paid - price

quarters = int(floor(change / 0.25))
change -= quarters * 0.25

dimes = int(floor(change / 0.1))
change -= dimes * 0.1

nickels = int(floor(change / 0.05))
change -= nickels * 0.05

pennies = int(floor(change / 0.01))
change -= pennies * 0.01

remaining = change

print("Quarters:", quarters)
print("Dimes:", dimes)
print("Nickels:", nickels)
print("Pennies:", pennies)
```

Personally I would also condense this into a loop over the coin type:

```
increments = {"quarter":0.25, "dimes": 0.1, "nickels": 0.05, "pennies": 0.01}
change_parts = {}
for inc_name, inc in increments.items():
    amount = int(floor(change / inc))
    print(inc_name, inc, amount)
    change -= amount * inc
    change_parts[inc_name] = amount

for inc_name, amount in change_parts.items():
    print(inc_name + ":", amount)
```